# VTK import makes python to crash

Tags: python, vtk

I've install vtk following [these instructions](http://www.it.uu.se/edu/course/homepage/vetvis/ht10/vtk/instructions_vtk_OSX.pdf) and setting in CMakeCache.txt

```
BUILD_SHARED_LIBS:BOOL=ON
PYTHON_EXECUTABLE:FILEPATH=/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
```

(the actual python running under ipython)

```
VTK_WRAP_PYTHON:BOOL=ON
```

the compilation succeeds but when i turn to python i get:

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Nov 28 2012, 13:43:07) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 0.13.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

In [1]: import pkgutil

In [2]: package = pkgutil.get_loader("vtk")

In [3]: package.filename
Out[3]: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/VTK-5.10.1-py2.7.egg/vtk'

In [4]: import vtk
Fatal Python error: Interpreter not initialized (version mismatch?)
Abort trap
```

anyone got an idea?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, though my Python crashed without giving me any error message. There are several differences between our situations, for example I'm running Windows 7 Professional 64-bit and my imports only broke after I installed 64-bit Python alongside the 32-bit. I didn't change anything to my 32-bit Python installation or my VTK-files, yet I couldn't get it to work in that configuration again.

Eventually I just recompiled VTK pointing to the 32-bit Python installation and that seemed to have solved the problem. Chances are high that our problems were completely unrelated and you've already solved yours, but I thought I should let you know.

One thing that's curious, though, is that output of the pkgutil command. Is '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/VTK-5.10.1-py2.7.egg/vtk' your VTK build directory? When I try the same command, I get: 'C:\Users\u0079931\64bit\VTK-bin\Wrapping\Python\vtk', which is more similar to the instructions you linked. Is your PYTHON_PATH set correctly?